# Socket raw, can't get response from tcp server in tcp handshake

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to send tcp SYN packet using socket raw with special structure sockaddr_ll, but my packet is ignored. My program should send SYN tcp packet and receive SYN/ACK packet. I tried to find a mistake and found that my packet has the wrong checksum and I fixed it, but nothing changed. How to fix it?

My packet:

[image]

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct ifreq if_idx;
    struct ifreq if_mac;
    struct ifreq ifreq_ip;
    int tx_len = 0;
    unsigned char* sendbuf;
    sendbuf=(unsigned char*)malloc(64); 
    memset(sendbuf,0,64);

    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));
    struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];
    
    /* Get interface name */
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(ifName, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(ifName, DEFAULT_IF);

    /* Open RAW socket to send on */
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
    }

    /* Get the index of the interface to send on */
    memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0)
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
    /* Get the MAC address of the interface to send on */
    memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0)
        perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR");
    /* get ip */
    memset(&ifreq_ip,0,sizeof(ifreq_ip));
    strncpy(ifreq_ip.ifr_name,ifName,IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if(ioctl(sockfd,SIOCGIFADDR,&ifreq_ip)<0)
    {
        printf("error in SIOCGIFADDR \n");
    }

    /* Construct the Ethernet header */
    /* Ethernet header */
    eh->ether_shost[0] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[0];
    eh->ether_shost[1] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[1];
    eh->ether_shost[2] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[2];
    eh->ether_shost[3] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[3];
    eh->ether_shost[4] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[4];
    eh->ether_shost[5] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[5];
    eh->ether_dhost[0] = MY_DEST_MAC0;
    eh->ether_dhost[1] = MY_DEST_MAC1;
    eh->ether_dhost[2] = MY_DEST_MAC2;
    eh->ether_dhost[3] = MY_DEST_MAC3;
    eh->ether_dhost[4] = MY_DEST_MAC4;
    eh->ether_dhost[5] = MY_DEST_MAC5;
    /* Ethertype field */
    eh->ether_type = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    
    tx_len += sizeof(struct ether_header);

    /* ip header */
    iph->ihl = 5;
    iph->version = 4;
    iph->tos = 0;
    iph->tot_len = htons(sizeof (struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    iph->id = htonl (01);   //Id of this packet
    iph->frag_off = 0;
    iph->ttl = 64;
    iph->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    iph->check = 0;     
    iph->saddr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa((((struct sockaddr_in *)&(ifreq_ip.ifr_addr))->sin_addr)));    
    iph->daddr = inet_addr ( "127.0.0.1" );
    
    //Ip checksum
    iph->check = 0xce7c;//csum ((unsigned short *) sendbuf, iph->tot_len);
    tx_len += sizeof(struct iphdr);

    //tcp
    tcph->source = htons (20);
    tcph->dest = htons (43521);
    tcph->seq = 0;
    tcph->ack_seq = 0;
    tcph->doff = 5; 
    tcph->fin=0;
    tcph->syn=1;
    tcph->rst=0;
    tcph->psh=0;
    tcph->ack=0;
    tcph->urg=0;
    tcph->window = htons (8192);    
    tcph->check = 0;    //leave checksum 0 now, filled later by pseudo header
    tcph->urg_ptr = 0;

    //Now the TCP checksum
    struct pseudo_header psh; 
    char* pseudogram;

    psh.source_address = inet_addr(inet_ntoa((((struct sockaddr_in *)&(ifreq_ip.ifr_addr))->sin_addr)));
    psh.dest_address = inet_addr ( "127.0.0.1" );
    psh.placeholder = 0;
    psh.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    psh.tcp_length = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    
    int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
    pseudogram = (char*)malloc(psize);
    
    memcpy(pseudogram , (char*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) , tcph , sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    
    tcph->check = csum( (unsigned short*) pseudogram , psize);

    tx_len+= sizeof(struct tcphdr);
    


    /* Index of the network device */
    socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
    /* Address length*/
    socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
    /* Destination MAC */
    socket_address.sll_addr[0] = MY_DEST_MAC0;
    socket_address.sll_addr[1] = MY_DEST_MAC1;
    socket_address.sll_addr[2] = MY_DEST_MAC2;
    socket_address.sll_addr[3] = MY_DEST_MAC3;
    socket_address.sll_addr[4] = MY_DEST_MAC4;
    socket_address.sll_addr[5] = MY_DEST_MAC5;
    socket_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;  

    /* Send packet */
    if (sendto(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0)
       printf("Send failed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are the MAC addresses actually filled out correctly? Are you sure it is arriving at the destination host? Have you compared it with a regular SYN from your TCP stack? Have you checked the receiver's statistics (eg. netstat) for errors?

Comment: MAC addresses are correct, I use virtualBox with ubuntu. How can I check statistics if I use socat tcp-listen?

Comment: When I've had to look at the raw headers (e.g. eth, IP, UDP, TCP), I've used `wireshark`

Comment: In your capture, the SRC and DST IP addresses are 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback.  I'm guessing by your code you are using linux, which has no link layer (ethernet) on the loopback.  If you are really intending to use the loopback, you need to go up a layer and use PF_INET/SOCK_RAW socket instead of a PF_PACKET/SOCK_RAW.

Comment: It's very strange that you're testing packet raw sockets via loopback. Please, try to do it in appropriate conditions. Also there must be `return`s after each `perror()`.